# Always getting "[object Object]" as output from custom string format function

Tags: javascript

I'm using a string format function copied direct from the StackOverflow source code; you can test it right now in the developer console with the following code:

```
"Logged in as {tag}, on {guilds} guild{s}".formatUnicorn({ tag: "TAG_HERE", guilds: "GUILD_COUNT", s: "s" });
```

I'm trying to use this exact same function, yet am always getting `[object Object]` as the output.

```
logger.info("bot", "Logged in as {tag}, on {guilds} guild{s}".format({ tag: client.user.tag, guilds: client.guilds.size, s: client.guilds.size === 1 ? "" : "s" }));
```

I've tried `require("util").inspect(...)`ing the Object that's returned, but that just outputs `'[object Object]'`, essentially the exact same thing but with single quotes surrounding it.

Here's the function, if that helps. I've renamed some of the variables for this question, though in testing the code it was a direct copy from the SO source:

```
String.prototype.format = () => {
  let string = this.toString();
  if(!arguments.length)
    return string;
  let type = typeof arguments[0],
    replacements = "string" == type || "number" == type ? Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) : arguments[0];
  for(const index in replacements)
    string = string.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + index + "\\}", "gi"), replacements[index]);
  return string;
}
```

This is likely a simple mistake with a simple solution but I've worked quite a while to try to diagnose the issue/get it working but finding nothing to fix it myself.

Comment: why you are using "typeof arguments[0]"?

Comment: That part's copied directly from the SO code. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions does [not bind its own](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments) `arguments` so your function will not work.

Changing from `String.prototype.format = () => {}` to `String.prototype.format = function () {}` will fix it for you.

Comment: Great, that fixes it! Never would've thought of it myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it hapens because you are using `this.toString();` and `this` is a json Object.

try it :

```
String.prototype.format = function() { ...
```

instead:

```
String.prototype.format = () => { ...
```